# Updating Task level custom fields

Tags: office365, csom, ms-project-server-2013

Using CSOM I can see how to use the SetCustomFieldValue method to update custom fields associated to a Project, but is it not possible to do this for a task within Project Online? I don't see anything that would allow this but it does list in the documentation this should be possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this thread? 
[Use CSOM to update project's custom fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/d79f22f2-7fd2-46af-b778-e189c8611120/use-csom-to-update-projects-custom-fields)

It's Project level but it may provide some further clues.
Actually, there's task level code at the bottom of that post so hopefully, that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've also searched for a way of updating task level custom fields, but couldn't find a solution.
For this and some other reasons I've decided to do this by implementing a projectdrilldown extension. This means to update the value directly in the project grid and let project server do the rest of the internal processing:

```
       _grid=window.projectDrilldownComponent.get_GridSatellite(); // get the grid

       // Update the datavalue of a column (taskfield) 
       _grid.WriteDataValueByKey(...)
       // Update the localizedvalue of a column (taskfield)
       _grid.WriteLocalizedValueByKey(rec_key, fieldkey, fieldvalue,
                function () {
                    console.log("Post Update task:" + rec_key);
                    cbSuccess();                        // callback after update                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a JSOM example to do this:

```
var projContext = PS.ProjectContext.get_current();    
var projects = projContext.get_projects();
var project = projects.getByGuid(projUid).get_draft();
var tasks = project.get_tasks();

var task = tasks.getByGuid(taskUid);

task.set_item(cfIntName, newValue);

var queueJob = project.update();

projContext.waitForQueueAsync(queueJob, 60, 
    Function.createDelegate(this, function(res) {
        // Publish project here
    }), function(error) {

    console.error(error);        
});
```

That should be complete (though I pulled it from a script, so check the success / failure handlers which I truncated)

From memory poking around in the CSOM there is no "set_item(cf, val)" helper method to use, but it was similar, I think the property is set on the object instance via an indexer, e.g.:

(sudo c# code)

```
var draftTask = [get task instance];
draftTask[cfInternalName] = "Some value";
```

etc.

If that doesn't help then you can always reflect the ProjectServer.Client.DLL and you'll see the internal implementation of "SetCustomFieldValue" which is not publicly exposed.

Hope that helps someone.