# Project Server 2013 - Update Task using REST ODATA

Tags: rest, server, odata, project, ms-project-server-2013

I wanted to update Project 'Task' metadata (for example the 'PercentComplete') from my own website. This update needs to be over HTTP as I am outside of hosted sharepoint server.

READ the property of Task using GET URL works:

https://myserver/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('proj_id')/Tasks('task_id')/PercentComplete

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:PercentComplete m:type="Edm.Int32">30</d:PercentComplete>
```

So I know authentication and validation works fine. But what call do I make to UPDATE this property of the Task.

I tried some of the posts like simple HTTP update with % in payload and creating a JSON with property name, but nothing works.

Could someone please share a code snippet that updates using javascript/jquery/ajax over HTTP to update the value from 30% to say 50%?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853398/updating-task-level-custom-fields/39325738#39325738